# Sorting upper case and lower case with Perl

Tags: perl

I tried to sorting upper case and lower case in the perl language. A bunch of text are save in as "electricity.txt"
in the .txt file:

> Today's scientific question is: What in the world is electricity and
> where does it go after it leaves the toaster?
>
> Here is a simple experiment that will teach you an important
> electrical lesson: On a cool dry day, scuff your feet along a carpet,
> then reach your hand into a friend's mouth and touch one of his dental
> fillings.  Did you notice how your friend twitched violently and cried
> out in pain?  This teaches one that electricity can be a very powerful
> force, but we must never use it to hurt others unless we need to learn
> an important lesson about electricity.

Somehow, I can't get any uppercase word
and my code is

```
my %count;
my $openFileile = "electricity.txt";
open my $openFile, '<', $openFileile;
while (my $list = <$openFile>) {
  chomp $list;
  foreach my $word (split /\s+/, $list) {
    $count{lc($word)}++;
  }
}
```

```
printf "\n\nSorting Alphabetically with upper case words in front of lower-case words with the same initial characters\n";
foreach my $word (sort keys %count){
  printf "%-31s \n", sort {"\$a" cmp uc"\$b"} lc($word);

}
```

Comment: You are using `lc` on the words to normalize them before putting them into your `%count` hash. There are no uppercase words after that.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue 1

First problem is the statement below means you are only storing the lower-case versions of all the words

```
$count{lc($word)}++;
```

After the initial `while` loop `%count` has only lower-case words. That means your `foreach` loop can never retrieve the upper-case words.

## Issue 2

Second issue is this statement

```
printf "%-31s \n", sort {"\$a" cmp uc"\$b"} lc($word);
```

I have no idea what you think that the `sort` will achieve -- it is sorting a list with only one element, `lc($word)`, so doesn't actually do anything.

## A working example

Taking the comments above into account, here is a version that outputs both upper & lower-case words (abbreviated)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
#my $openFileile = "electricity.txt";
#open my $openFile, '<', $openFileile;
while (my $list = <DATA>) {
  chomp $list;
  foreach my $word (split /\s+/, $list) {
    $count{$word}++;
  }
}

printf "\n\nSorting Alphabetically with upper case words in front of lower-case words with the same initial characters\n";
foreach my $word (sort keys %count){
  printf "%-31s \n", $word;

}
__DATA__
Today's scientific question is: What in the world is electricity and where does it go after it leaves the toaster?

Here is a simple experiment that will teach you an important electrical lesson: On a cool dry day, scuff your feet along a carpet, then reach your hand into a friend's mouth and touch one of his dental fillings. Did you notice how your friend twitched violently and cried out in pain? This teaches one that electricity can be a very powerful force, but we must never use it to hurt others unless we need to learn an important lesson about electricity.
```

That print this

```
Sorting Alphabetically with upper case words in front of lower-case words with the same initial characters
Did                             
Here                            
On                              
This                            
Today's                         
What                            
a                               
about                           
after                           
along    
...
use                             
very                            
violently                       
we                              
where                           
will                            
world                           
you
```

Answer (score 3):

As Hunter McMillen's comment says, you are using `lc` on the words when creating the hash, therefore all of your original capitalization will be lost. Lets go through your code, as I spot some other mistakes.

First off, always use `use strict; use warnings`. Especially if you have a preference for long and complicated variable names. It will save you from typos and weird bugs.

```
open my $openFile, '<', $openFileile;
```

With `open` statements, it is idiomatic to check the return value of the open, to see if anything went wrong. And if it did, to report the error. I.e. add `..., or die "Cannot open '$openFileile': $!"`.

```
  foreach my $word (split /\s+/, $list) {
```

Typically, if you split on whitespace you usually want to split on `' '` -- a single space. This is a special case for `split`, also the default split mode, it will split on `\s+`, but also remove leading whitespace.

```
    $count{lc($word)}++;
```

Here is your problem. All the words lose their original case.

```
printf "\n\nSorting Alphabetically with upper case words in front of lower-case words with the same initial characters\n";
```

`printf` is a special formatting print. If you do not intend to use that formatting, use the regular `print` to avoid problems.

```
  printf "%-31s \n", sort {"\$a" cmp uc"\$b"} lc($word);
```

1. You cannot sort just one (1) word. You need at least 2 words to be able to sort.
2. Why are you using double quotes, and then escaping the variable sigil? I am guessing this is you testing different things to see what works. This looks very unlikely to do what you want.
   `"\$a"` will just become `$a` -- a dollar sign plus an "a". This is what you do when you want to print the variable name, e.g. `print "\$a is $a"` (prints `$a is 12`, for example).
3. `lc` will have no effect, since all your words are already in lower case.
4. Even if `lc` and `uc` would work here, you cannot use `uc` like that in the `sort` subroutine. The sort function will choose one word in the comparison at random and capitalize it. Effectively destroying your sort.

Also uc will change all the letters to upper case (cat => CAT). You want `ucfirst` (cat => Cat).

When I clean up your code, and also make the variable names somewhat more reasonable, I get this below. Also, I removed your file open, since I use the internal `DATA` file handle to facilitate testing. You can just put back your own open, with the additions I described above.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %words;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    for my $word (split ' ', $line) { # split on ' ' a single space removes leading and trailing whitespace
        my $key = lc $word;           # save lowercase word as key 
        $words{$key}{count}++;        # separate count 
        $words{$key}{value} = $word;  # word original formatting as value
    }
}

# printf is used for special formatting, if you are not using that formatting, use regular print to avoid unnecessary interpolation of %
print "\nSorting Alphabetically with upper case words in front of lower-case words with the same initial characters\n";
for my $word (sort keys %words) {
    printf "%-31s : %s\n", $words{$word}{value}, $words{$word}{count};
}

__DATA__
Today's scientific question is: What in the world is electricity and where does it go after it leaves the toaster?
Here is a simple experiment that will teach you an important electrical lesson: On a cool dry day, scuff your feet along a carpet, then reach your hand into a friend's mouth and touch one of his dental fillings. Did you notice how your friend twitched violently and cried out in pain? This teaches one that electricity can be a very powerful force, but we must never use it to hurt others unless we need to learn an important lesson about electricity.
```

And it prints

```
a                               : 5
about                           : 1
after                           : 1
along                           : 1
an                              : 2
and                             : 3
be                              : 1
but                             : 1
can                             : 1
carpet,                         : 1
cool                            : 1
...etc
```

As can be noticed, this differentiates between `carpet` and `carpet,` since you are only splitting on whitespace. It keeps the non-word characters and includes them in the hash. There are different ways to find words in a text. For example, instead of split you could use a regex:

```
my @words = $line =~ /\w+/g;   # \w is word characters, plus numbers, and underscore _
```

Even this is simplistic, but will work better than your split. You can add characters to the regex as your needs require, for example: `/[\w\-]+/` -- include dash for hyphenated words, e.g. `mega-carpet`. (Note that dash `-` has to be escaped when placed between other characters inside a character class bracket, otherwise it will be interpreted as a range, e.g. `a-z`.)